# jQuery to fetch time from full calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to manually input the time in the modal , however everytime the modal pops up the time input field has already a value which is the current time in my computer's clock.

How do I edit the javascript so that it will not generate the time automatically.
I used the plug in here https://github.com/tliokos/jquery-fullcalendar-crud . I just Downloaded it. By the way it is my first time to use this plug in.

This is the javascript code:

```
$(function(){
var currentDate; // Holds the day clicked when adding a new event
var currentEvent; // Holds the event object when editing an event
$('#color').colorpicker(); // Colopicker
$('#time').timepicker({
    minuteStep: 5,
    showInputs: false,
    disableFocus: true,
    showMeridian: false
});  // Timepicker
// Fullcalendar
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',
    header: {
        left: 'prev, next, today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month, basicWeek, basicDay'
    },
    // Get all events stored in database
    events: 'crud/getEvents.php',
    // Handle Day Click
    dayClick: function(date, event, view) {
        currentDate = date.format();
        // Open modal to add event
        modal({
            // Available buttons when adding
            buttons: {
                add: {
                    id: 'add-event', // Buttons id
                    css: 'btn-success', // Buttons class
                    label: 'Add' // Buttons label
                }
            },
            title: 'Add Event (' + date.format() + ')' // Modal title
        });
    },
    // Event Mouseover
    eventMouseover: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view){
        var tooltip = '<div class="event-tooltip">' + calEvent.description + '</div>';
        $("body").append(tooltip);
        $(this).mouseover(function(e) {
            $(this).css('z-index', 10000);
            $('.event-tooltip').fadeIn('500');
            $('.event-tooltip').fadeTo('10', 1.9);
        }).mousemove(function(e) {
                $('.event-tooltip').css('top', e.pageY + 10);
                $('.event-tooltip').css('left', e.pageX + 20);
            });
    },
    eventMouseout: function(calEvent, jsEvent) {
        $(this).css('z-index', 8);
        $('.event-tooltip').remove();
    },
    // Handle Existing Event Click
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        // Set currentEvent variable according to the event clicked in the calendar
        currentEvent = calEvent;
        // Open modal to edit or delete event
        modal({
            // Available buttons when editing
            buttons: {
                delete: {
                    id: 'delete-event',
                    css: 'btn-danger',
                    label: 'Delete'
                },
                update: {
                    id: 'update-event',
                    css: 'btn-success',
                    label: 'Update'
                }
            },
            title: 'Edit Event "' + calEvent.title + '"',
            event: calEvent
        });
    }
});
// Prepares the modal window according to data passed
```

Comment: what time do you expect it to show when it opens up ?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest looking at the docs for the timepicker.
https://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/

In which case set defaultTime=false

defaultTime 
'current' (default) - Set to the current time.
Set to a specific time - '11:45 AM'
false   - Do not set a default time